# How do I delete all X days old documents from the Java API?

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the question is "how do I write a query for documents that are X days old so I can delete them".

**END OF EDIT**

Our code indexes results from a query using ElasticSearch. We want to run a clean up job once a day to delete all old documents. We currently do so by calling an external script, but to cut down on the dependencies we would love to do it from Java.

I can't figure out how to query for the old documents using the API... Clues, help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you delete documents which have been stored for a certain amount of time you can set a TTL (time-to-live) parameter, setting the documents deletion bit-set flag once this time has elapsed. See [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html). Hope this is an alternative you could consider.

**UPDATE**

```
"query":{
  "match_all": {}
},
"filter":{
  range:{
   "field":{
     lte: 20140225,
     gte: 20140201
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to delete by a query.  So this is the Java API

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/delete-by-query.html

for

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

for deleting date ranges use a range query

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

e.g. with `range: lt: '2014-01-01'`

Comment: I have found that already, but need an example of how to query for documents to delete based on their age...

Comment: i have added the range query.  but quite honest, i like the TTL appropach alot better.  i'd even rather put the docs on e.g. indices per day, put the "hot" indices in an alias and when they get old, just remove the index from the alias and delete the whole index.  it all depends on how much logic is needed to define "old".